Where is the default Android boot animation stored?
I know where the manufacturer boot animation is stored - /system/media/bootanimation.zip. But I don't know where the actual android animation stored (it appears, when bootanimation.zip is corrupted or doesn't exists). And I mean animation that has "Android" logo at the center.

Maybe you should tell us what you are trying to achieve
